# How to add data to a list so I can render it for the recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to render a list to my recycler view but since I have not added the data I get from the API to the list I pass to the recycler, I cannot see the results. How would I go about doing that?

This is the data returned from it.data and since it.data returns the data as a whole, I cannot pick each field like I need to:

```
[Character(id=1, name=Rick Sanchez, gender=Male), Character(id=2, name=Morty Smith, gender=Male), Character(id=3, name=Summer Smith, gender=Female), Character(id=4, name=Beth Smith, gender=Female), Character(id=5, name=Jerry Smith, gender=Male), Character(id=6, name=Abadango Cluster Princess, gender=Female), Character(id=7, name=Abradolf Lincler, gender=Male), Character(id=8, name=Adjudicator Rick, gender=Male), Character(id=9, name=Agency Director, gender=Male), Character(id=10, name=Alan Rails, gender=Male), Character(id=11, name=Albert Einstein, gender=Male), Character(id=12, name=Alexander, gender=Male), Character(id=13, name=Alien Googah, gender=unknown), Character(id=14, name=Alien Morty, gender=Male), Character(id=15, name=Alien Rick, gender=Male), Character(id=16, name=Amish Cyborg, gender=Male), Character(id=17, name=Annie, gender=Female), Character(id=18, name=Antenna Morty, gender=Male), Character(id=19, name=Antenna Rick, gender=Male), Character(id=20, name=Ants in my Eyes Johnson, gender=Male)]
```

This is the whole activity:

```
package com.app.mortyapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.app.mortyapp.Model.CharacterRepository
import com.app.mortyapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var  binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val characters = mutableListOf<Character>()
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels(
        factoryProducer = {MainViewModelFactory()}
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        progressBar = binding.ProgressBar
        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        initRecyclerView()
        setObservers()


    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        with(binding.rvCharacters){
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(characters).apply {
                setCharacterList(characters)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addData(id:Int, name:String, gender:String){
        characters.add(Character(id,name,gender))
    }
    private fun setObservers(){
        viewModel.characterList.observe(this, Observer {
            when(it.status){
                NetworkStatus.LOADING ->{
                    //show loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                NetworkStatus.SUCCESS -> {
                    //hide loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    //render character list
                    Log.d("DATA RECYCLER BR: ", "${recyclerAdapter.itemCount}}") //returns 0
                    it.data?.let { it1 -> recyclerAdapter.setCharacterList(it1) }
                    Log.d("DATA IS THIS: ", "${it.data}") //returns correct data
                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    Log.d("DATA RECYCLER: ", "${recyclerAdapter.itemCount}}") //returns 20
                    addData(it.data(id,name,gender)) // does not work
                }

                NetworkStatus.ERROR -> {
                    //show error message
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error loading content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //hide loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I made this function to add the data to the characters list so I can pass it to the recycler adapter but I can't pass the data for the reasons I explained above:

```
    private fun addData(id:Int, name:String, gender:String){
        characters.add(Character(id,name,gender))
    }
```

How would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line.

```
initRecyclerView()
    setObservers()
```

With

```
    setObservers()
    initRecyclerView()
```

And

```
private fun initRecyclerView() {
    with(binding.rvCharacters){
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(characters).apply {
            setCharacterList(characters)
        }
    adatper = recyclerAdapter // add this line also
    }
}
```

It should be work.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't

Comment: Check now . I think you not set adapter for RV.